Proxmox metrics missing in exporter (PVE 8.2.4)
I installed the prometheus-pve-exporter on docker hosted by the proxmox. However, the metrics are missing. Only supporting items are available...
Such as:
pve_collection_duration_seconds_count{module="default"} 0.0
pve_collection_duration_seconds_sum{module="default"} 0.0
pve_collection_duration_seconds_created{module="default"} 1.7205230564812522e+09
pve_request_errors_total{module="default"} 91.0
pve_request_errors_created{module="default"} 1.7205230564812417e+09

I tried to installed in venv with the same results.

This seems to be a sysadmin question. Consider [sf], [su] or [devops.se].

It was an issue of misconfiguration. I didn't carefully follow the manual.

If you found the solution, then it would be great, if you would share it. This way others could benefit.
